# chrome / safari (webkit) loose border-radius on pointer interaction

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, css

I am facing a problem with a list inside a div. The thing is, I have a div with a list inside. This limits the amount of div intens that will appear to the user. When the limit is exceeded will see a scroll inside this div, for the user to view other intens, this same div has a rounded edge (border-radius) at the bottom. When I move the mouse over the LAST ITEM LIST, it removes the effect of border-radius of div. Who can help me here is a file jsFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/Vqu7n/22/)

[image]
[image]

```
 .limit {
height:300px;
width:500px;
background-color:red;
overflow: scroll;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6x;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6x;
}
```

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: No need to add "solved" to the title.  This is not a forum, the system already displays if an answer is accepted by showing the number of answers in yellow. [meta discusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's caused by

```
li { ... position:relative; ... }
```

remove that from `li` and apply it to a nested element (ie `li > .somediv`) and make this one transparent... no borders, backgrounds, etc.

---

update: a nicer workaround http://jsfiddle.net/YcYHd/

Add `outline:1px transparent solid` to the scrolling element.

Apparently this seems to prevent the bug

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your time! That was a good trick, solved the problem ... I thought nobody would see this bug! Thank you again, cheers.